# Merge two dataframes on multiple columns but only merge on columns if both not NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking to merge two dataframes across multiple columns but with some additional conditions.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['a','b','c', 'd'],
    'optional_col2': ['X',None,'Z','V'],
    'optional_col3': [None,'def', 'ghi','jkl']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['a','b','c', 'd'],
    'optional_col2': ['X','Y','Z','W'],
    'optional_col3': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi','mno']
})
```

I would like to always join on `col1` but then try to also join on `optional_col2` and `optional_col3`. In `df1`, the value can be `NaN` for both columns but it is always populated in `df2`. I would like the join to be valid when the `col1` + one of `optional_col2` or `optional_col3` match.

This would result in `['a', 'b', 'c']` joining due to exact `col2`, `col3`, and exact match, respectively.

In SQL I suppose you could write the join as this, if it helps explain further:

```
select
    *
from
    df1
        inner join
    df2
        on df1.col1 = df2.col2
        AND (df1.optional_col2 = df2.optional_col2 OR df1.optional_col3 = df2.optional_col3)
```

I've messed around with `pd.merge` but can't figure how to do a complex operation like this. I think I can do a merge on `['col1', 'optional_col2']` then a second merge on `['col1', 'optional_col_3']` then union and drop duplicates?

Expected DataFrame would be something like:

```
merged_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'optional_col_2': ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
    'optional_col_3': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
})
```

Comment: can you provide the expected output dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

This solution works by creating an extra column called "temp" in both dataframes.  In `df11` it will be a column of true values.  In `df2` the values will be true if there is a match between either of the optional columns.  I'm not clear whether you consider a `NaN` value to be matchable or not, if so then you need to fill in the `NaN`s of columns in `df1` with values from `df2` before comparing to fulfill your criteria around missing values (this is what is below).  If this is not required then drop the `fillna` calls in the example below.

```
df1["temp"] = True
optional_col2_match = df1["optional_col2"].fillna(df2["optional_col2"]).eq(df2["optional_col2"])
optional_col3_match = df1["optional_col3"].fillna(df2["optional_col3"]).eq(df2["optional_col3"])
df2["temp"] = optional_col2_match | optional_col3_match
```

Then use the "temp" column in the merge, and then drop it - it has served its purpose

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["col1", "temp"]).drop(columns="temp")
```

This gives the following result

```
  col1 optional_col2_x optional_col3_x optional_col2_y optional_col3_y
0    a               X             abc               X             abc
1    b               Y             def               Y             def
2    c               Z             ghi               Z             ghi
```

You will need to decide what to do here.  In the example you gave there are no rows which match on just one of `optional_col2` and `optional_col2`, which is why a 3 column solution looks reasonable.  This won't generally be the case.